# How browsers manage styles load order priority?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a Symfony2 project and I defined a block called `{% block styles %}` on the main layout. This block is where I add some extra styles if any bundle needs it. That's works fine. Now in a bundle I've this:

```
{% block styles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/plantilla/components/fuelux/dist/css/fuelux.min.css') }}"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fuelux .wizard > .actions a {
            font-size: 0 !important;
            line-height: 0 !important;
            margin-right: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock styles %}
```

It's not supposed that browsers load the styles in the order they appear? If so, then why I'm running into this:

Information from Firebug HTML tab > Style: load order is totally wrong
[image]

Information from Firebug HTML tab: load order appears to be good
[image]

As a second part of this question I have another doubt, exists a easy way to override the whole CSS selector properties without need to override one by one? Notice in the first attached image what I'm doing; I'm overriding the `.fuelux .wizard > .actions a` property, so any easy way to get this or necessarily needs to be one by one?

**Edit: adding test**

Ok, at first I was confused, now I made a simple test and see the results below:

**With styles, both applied:**
[image]

**Without styles (notice I'm removed all in Firebug):**
[image]

So I'll rewrite the answer by:

What's is the right way to override the styles in order to get them out? Exists a easy way to override the whole CSS selector properties without need to override one by one? Notice in the first attached image what I'm doing; I'm overriding the `.fuelux .wizard > .actions a` property, so any easy way to get this or necessarily needs to be one by one?

**PS:** Before downvote or vote for close the topic I must say I set `javascript` and `jquery` tags since maybe there is one way using Javascript for override the whole CSS selector properties instead of only CSS

Comment: Please don't use `!important`...

Comment: since you have used `!important` it will have priority over other rules... also the style that is loaded second will override the style that was loaded first if both rules has the same specificity

Comment: @ArunPJohny that's the issue, I don't know why this is happening, the intention is to override the default rules with my own, but even, using `!important` it's not working since inline are render before the default and that's the issue

Comment: @MattBall this is my intention, override the default style the one at `fuelux.min.css line 7` with the one I set inline with `!important`

Comment: so are you saying that the rules with `!important` is not getting applied

Comment: @ArunPJohny not at all, perhaps them are applied but are override by the default ones

Comment: but your firefox style tab shows that the styles are applied properly

Comment: @ArunPJohny place take a look to my edit (should I change the answer title and content or should I leave as it?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63073/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-reynierpm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussions, OP want to reapply a set of style values from bootstrap which were overridden by fuelux.. As far I know since the fuelux has more specific rules the only option is to create a rule yourself and apply the style values you want

```
.fuelux .wizard > .actions a.btn {
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qovbfzfa/)

Answer (score 3):

Inline styles have the **highest priority** of all CSS. Generally, its recommend you avoid using them but you may not have that luxury if you are working on a legacy system or do not have direct access to the HTML code.

Fortunately, besides JS based solutions, there is a CSS-only way to override inline styles:

```
.fuelux .wizard > .actions a[style] {
        font-size: 0 !important;
        line-height: 0 !important;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
```

This method will work in all major browser (except IE 6 & 7), including:

- Internet Explorer 8.0
- Mozilla Firefox 2 and 3
- Opera 9
- Apple Safari,
- Google Chrome

**EDITED TO ADD:** Looks like its not about overriding the inline CSS afterall, since your inline styles are being rendered, you just have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: the idea is not "override inline styles from an external stylesheet" is the inverse "override external styles from inline styles" that's is, apparently, not working for me or I'm applying the rules in the wrong way

Comment: @ReynierPM Do you mean the default button styles that come with the bootstrap theme, you need to get rid of those so you can style your own?

Comment: yes, take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4x0mn9ud/) the idea is convert the `a` element on the left like the `button` element on the right and this is what I can't get

Comment: @ReynierPM http://jsfiddle.net/4x0mn9ud/2/ -- Well, you can't have `<style>` tags in the stylesheet.

Comment: yes, I can't have it on fiddle, take a look to [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4x0mn9ud/1/) instead this is working and do this test, open Firebug and select the a element, remove on the fly the inline .fuelux .wizard > .actions a and the default .fuelux .wizard > .actions a and you'll see the result, this is what I'm looking for